# Why do I get very inconsistent Google Geocode API results?

Tags: google-api, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have a list of a few thousand locations for which I need to find the coordinates. I'm using Google Geocode API for this.

The information I have is something like "USA, California, Napa Valley"

So my Geocode call would look something like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Napa+Valley,California,USA&key=<apikey>`

(I put them in reverse order and replace spaces with "+" characters)

I'm of course mostly interested in the values found under `['results'][0]['geometry']['location']` key (where latitude and longitude will be found).

Now in a lot of cases I get very different results by simply waiting a few hours or 1 day and making the call again. And I make those calls using the exact same data, same parameters, same everything

Usually the coordinates are different by a fraction of a degree or at most 1.0 - 1.5 degrees. For example 39.8 latitude yesterday becomes 40.4 latitude today. And then it becomes 40.1. And then a day after it comes back to 39.8. And then it's 40.25. And so on...

However in some extreme cases the differences are massive.

Actual concrete example:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Côtes+du+Rhône-Brézème,Northern+Rhône,Rhône,France&key=<apikey>`

The result will be something like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            .....
            "formatted_address": "Rhône",
            "geometry": {
                .........
                "location": {
                    "lat": 44.952398,
                    "lng": 6.4840823
                }
            },
            "partial_match": true,
            ......
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

So it's somewhat correctly identified as the Rhone region in France.

However if I wait just a few minutes and make the call again, I get this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
        ......
         "formatted_address" : "148 Chambers St A, New York, NY 10007, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.715666,
               "lng" : -74.009906
            },
            ......
         },
         .....
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Since when is Rhone/France even close to New-York ?

And this is the annoying part: I don't change anything about the URL. I simply make the EXACT same call a few minutes apart.

My thinking was that it was caused by me not properly encoding the URL.

However, while this may be true, I found it happens for queries that use NO special characters at all, for example something like `Clarksburg,California,USA`. In this case though I get 2 different results (coordinates), both in California, about 200 miles from each other.

---

Why does this happen? I need consistent results by this API. I don't need extreme precision or something like that. But at least some strong consistency.

I can't just go through a few thousand locations and put them manually in Google-Maps website to find their coordinates. It would take me 1 week of non-stop work...

Comment: This issue is now reported on Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116821440

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug that would be best reported in the Google Maps APIs public issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/code/p/gmaps-api-issues/